# How to handle vanity replacement when finish materials do not continue behind existing unit?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, leak, vanity

I had a plumbing leak under my bathroom sink that soaked the vanity before it was discovered and the water shut off. The vanity is cheap crap made out of particleboard that has swelled up like a balloon as a result. What a terrible choice of material. So now I need to replace the vanity with one of much higher quality, but there's a hitch: the bathroom was remodeled by the previous owners, and whoever did the work either didn't remove the vanity before doing the work, or else cheaped out on it to save on materials costs: the floor and baseboard tile was terminated at the base of the vanity, and walls behind it were not finished.

If I remove the vanity, there's a glaringly unfinished area of the bathroom. It seems like I need to replace the vanity with one of identical dimensions or else I'll have a ton of finish work to do, including hunting down several different types of tile that were used for the tile baseboards, which seems impossible.

What are my options here?

Comment: You don't need one of exactly the same size; a little bigger would also work. This just requires removing material, not matching. You could also place a tile border around the vanity using whatever design you want. It doesn't need to match, just look complementary. Finally, I'd suggest a trip down to your local hardware store with a picture of the tiles in question. You might get lucky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up replacing the vanity with a slightly larger one and cutting the tile a bit with an angle grinder to make enough room.